# Can I create visual web part for SharePoint online in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, 2016, error, visual-web-part

I tried to create a visual web part and publish it to SharePoint online:

I created a visual web part at local using SharePoint server 2016 and to publish to SharePoint online, I selected "Sandboxed Solutions".

[image]

I tried to run test at local and publish to SP Online, but both throws errors:

> $Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;

[image]

[image]

Can I create visual web part for SharePoint online in SharePoint 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code based sandbox solutions contain server-side code and the solution contains .Net assembly file (.dll). SharePoint online doesnot support Code-based sandbox solutions.

You could transform sandbox solutions to the SharePoint Add-in model:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/sandbox-solution-transformation-guidance

Comment: But sharepoint add-in is a application or a page, it is not a part of page. can't create a webpart for SP Online by visual studio?

Comment: For SharePoint online, we can only create client-side web parts: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts

Comment: Thank you, your information.

Comment: If my answer helps you, please accept it :)